# MongooseJS: How can I turn a Mongoose Collection into a standard Javascript array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to send a database collection directly to the client. When inspecting the collection on the client it appears to be a Mongoose object with various mongoose methods attached to it. How can I get to the raw collection data and ditch the mongoose object?

I have managed to get the following to do what I want, but seems a little hacky:

```
var normalJavascriptArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myMongooseCollection));
```

Answer (score 3):

<s>You can call the toObject() function. I know it says toObject, but in this case it returns an array.</s>

Source: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray-toObject

What I actually had to do when trying it was map through the resulting array and call toObject on each of its children. The mongoose docs were talking about a subdocument array I think.

```
MyMongooseCollection.map(function(item){
    return item.toObject();
}
```

Tested. It works.

Comment: Although after trying this... its not actually correct. I will edit.